# Why was the recent question about Democrats inciting riots put on-hold WITH comments disabled?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, comments

So this question:

https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/35561/21907

...was asked over in Politics SE and migrated here, but the migration was rejected, and it was put on-hold, *but the comments were disabled too*. Why were the comments disabled?

They didn't disable them in Politics SE. At best this seems impulsive as the question, though subjective, could be easily salvaged I think. At worst this comes across as censorship.

Comment: The comments are disabled because rejected migrations are automatically locked. This is an entirely automatic system.

Comment: Further to that: closing the question here sends it back to [politics.se], where the comments are still present and active. There's no point having the same stuff over here.

Comment: Ah, gotchya. Together these comments make a good answer that I would accept.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe these to hold truth:

The comments are disabled because rejected migrations are automatically locked. This is an entirely automatic system.

Further to that: closing the question here sends it back to [Politics](https://politics.stackexchange.com/), where the comments are still present and active. There's no point having the same stuff over here